# ZendExtensionManager.so: cannot open shared object file

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, zend-server

I just updated my apache installation (via easyapache in cpanel) so that mod_deflate would be enabled and I also updated PHP from 5.3 to 5.4 in the process. After doing this I found a redirect loop was happening on a Wordpress site on the server.

After banging my head against a wall I opened a question on Wordpress Answers: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/123037/redirect-loop-in-wp-admin - the answers led to the conclusion that the error resulted from the php version update.

I found the following error appears in my apache error log every time I try accessing the page with the redirect loop:

> [Tue Nov 12 15:46:40 2013] [error] [client 151.230.62.182] Failed loading /usr/local/Zend/lib/ZendExtensionManager.so:  /usr/local/Zend/lib/ZendExtensionManager.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
>   [Tue Nov 12 15:46:40 2013] [error] [client 151.230.62.182] Premature end of script headers: index.php

That error iterates itself several times each time I attempt to access the /wp-admin/ url.

I've checked and there is no folder `/usr/local/Zend/` - is that bad? If so how can I go about fixing this issue.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Look in your Apache/Apache Mods and php.ini if any module gets loaded pointing to that lib or similiar then disable that line with `#` or `;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ultimately the only answer I found was to revert the PHP version back to 5.3 - issue solved for now.